# How to add a Monotouch.Dialog.Element to UIView.AddSubview

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

In simple terms, I want to add an Monotouch.Dialog.Element to an UIView using UIView.AddSubview. What do I need to change/create to make this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `MonoTouch.Dialog.Element` is based on a `UITableViewCell`, not on a `UIView`.

Because of this, the `Element` should be part of a `UITableView` and can not simply be added to a `UIView` as a `SubView`.

If you want to have a `UIView` similar to an `Element`, you have to create a custom view, inheriting from a `UIView`. In this view, you can create the behavior you like from the `View` inside the `UITableViewCell` of the `Element` of your choice.

Edit: a basic example based on the MultiLineElement

```
public class MyView : UIView
{
  private string Caption { get; set; }          
  private string Text { get; set; }

  public View(string caption, string text) : base()
  {
    Opaque = true;
    BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
    Update(caption, text);
  }

  public void Update(string caption, string text)
  {
    Caption = caption;
    Text = text;

    SetNeedsDisplay();
  }

  public override void Draw(RectangleF frame)
  {
    var bounds = Bounds;
    var captionFont = UIFont.BoldSystemFontOfSize(12f);
    var textFont = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(10f);
    var width = Bounds.Width;

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Caption) == false)
    {
      // Caption, black
      UIColor.Black.SetColor();
      width = Bounds.Width / 2;
      var captionHeight = 
        StringSize(Caption, captionFont, width, UILineBreakMode.TailTruncation).Height;
      var captionOffset = textFont.PointSize - captionFont.PointSize;
      DrawString(Caption, new RectangleF(0, captionOffset, width, captionHeight),
        captionFont, UILineBreakMode.TailTruncation, UITextAlignment.Right);
    }

    // Text, dark gray
    UIColor.DarkGray.SetColor();
    var textHeight = 
      StringSize(Text, textFont, width, UILineBreakMode.WordWrap).Height;
    DrawString(Text, new RectangleF(Bounds.Width - width, 0, width, textHeight), 
      textFont, UILineBreakMode.WordWrap);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, although the solution as described in your last paragraph is not clear to me - can you provide a simple example?

Comment: I'll try to provide an example in a few hours.

Comment: I added an example, which is very basic, but hopefully will get you started.